# Toggle between MapFragment and ListFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, mapfragment, android-nested-fragment

I am creating an App where I want to switch between my `CustomMapFragment` and a `ListFragment`. If I start the App and call `replaceFragment`:

```
private void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = mActivity.getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

with `replaceFragment(new CustomMapFragment())` the `Map` looks like it should.

The `CustomMapFragment` is a Fragment where I replace a `FrameLayout` with the native `MapFragment`, to have it separated from the code.

If I call the replace method again on button click or something, with a different `Fragment` (the `ListFragment` for example), the `FrameLayout` gets replaced with this, everything is fine.

If I now try to replace it again with the `CustomMapFragment`, the exact same call like on the beginning, the `Map` is loaded but it is missing every `Marker` and every Setting I have done in the `CustomMapFragment`.

**`CustomMapFragment`**:

```
public class CustomMapFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PosMapFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap   mMap;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private Context     mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = getActivity();

        final RequestQueue reqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(reqQueue, new BitmapLruCache(mContext));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
        replaceFragment(mMapFragment);
    }

    private void postMapInitialisation() {
        new View(getActivity()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                addTestMarker(0, 0, "http://www.jimis-cyberstore.com/store/media/gp_batman_tshirts.jpg");
                addTestMarker(10, 10, "http://img.netzwelt.de/software/icons/2012/8842/android-sdk.png");
                addTestMarker(50, 50, "http://fs02.androidpit.info/ali/x84/4053084-1374511678988-80x80.png");
                addTestMarker(5, 0, "http://im.wk.io/images/77e3e40/kitkat-chromium-ubernimmt-in-android.jpeg");
                addTestMarker(0, 10, "http://www.mchme.de/cms/kategorien/18_Software/dateien/fb_logo_80.jpg");
                addTestMarker(15, 5, "http://navigator.ptvgroup.com/uploads/pics/PTV_Navigator_Android_Windows2_80x80px_01.png");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        postMapInitialisation();
        EventBusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }

    private void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.maps, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = mMapFragment.getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);
                mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addTestMarker(final double lat, final double lng, String url){
        if(mMap != null){
            final NetworkImageMarker networkImageMarker = new NetworkImageMarker(mContext, url);
            final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(networkImageMarker.getMarkerOptions(lat, lng, mImageLoader));
            networkImageMarker.setMarker(marker);
            networkImageMarker.setReloadListener(new OnReloadListener() {
                @Override
                public void reAddNetworkImageMarker(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    mMap.addMarker(networkImageMarker.getMarkerOptions(lat, lng, bitmap));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onLocationChanged(final LocationChangedEvent event) {
        centerMap(event.mLocation);
    }

    private void centerMap(Location location){
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        centerMapAtLocation(latLng);
    }

    private void centerMapAtLocation(LatLng location) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
    }
}
```

The main layout is just a `FrameLayout`, which get replaced for different `Fragment`s. I also tried to load just one `Fragment` where the `CustomMapFragment` and the `ListFragment` are loaded at the same time, with two `FrameLayout`s, so they are **stacked** over each other, but it ends up in the same behavior.

It seems there is something wrong with the `MapFragment` (not the `SupportMapFragment`).

- loading `MapFragment` at the beginning = `MapFragment` looks perfect
- `MapFragment` -> `ListFragment` -> `MapFragment` = `MapFragment` is an empty Map
- `ListFragment` -> `MapFragment` = `MapFragment` is an empty Map
- `MapFragment` -> `MapFragment` = `MapFragment` is an empty Map

Comment: Does it make a difference when you call `postMapInitialisation()` within `setUpMapIfNeeded()`?

Comment: `setUpMapIfNeeded()` is just called in `onResume()` and `postMapInitialisation()` is always called after `setUpMapIfNeeded()`. So I guess it would make no difference.

Comment: Please try moving `postMapInitialisation()` into your if-condition. I suspect the `map` is still `null`.

Comment: I did but nothing changed - it seems the Map is a different Map as the first loaded one. It also has no Settings enabled like MyLocation or compass. While debugging I have seen that he adds the Marker and also setup the Map. I think there are two Maps over each other for some reason.

Comment: Please check for two things: (1) Add an `else` clause in `addTestMarker()` to cover when `mMap == null`. (2) In your Activity check if the instance of `CustomMapFragment` is the same.

Comment: the map is always null after the second call, even after `fragment.getMap()` is called. if i call `replaceFragment` I always use `new Fragment()`. This works for all fragments instead of the one with the `MapFragment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to replace fragments **inside** of another fragment, you should use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() in your replace method.

```
private void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.maps, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Unfortunately getChildFragmentManager() is only supported for api lvl >= 17, so you will probably have to use the android-support-v4 library.

Comment: I had a problem that the list's footer disappears on toggle. Using getChildFragmentManager solved my problem